# Issue Creating Function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python Development . I guess this is my third day into python development.And i am getting this issue  **Did you create a function called shut_down?**.

Is there anything i am missing a here is a string.

Below is the code snippet that i have done but i am getting a issue.

```
def shut_down(a):
    if a.lower() == 'yes':
        return "Shutting down..."
    elif a.lower() != yes and len(a)!=0:
        return "Sorry, I didn't understand you."
    else:
        return "Shutdown aborted!"
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the `"yes"` into quotes, in your `elif` statement.
Read the errors Python shows you, it contains useful information. You could have spotted this one easily.

Also note that you can just test `and len(a)` without `!=0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.How careless  :( i could be sorry for the trouble.